Past perfect to emphasize a duration?

My time in the Bay Area was in stages. I first moved out there in the late eighties, when I went to school at Cabrillo College in Aptos, just south of Santa Cruz. I went out to San Francisco in 1987 for the first time when I was 17 years old and growing up in Pensacola, FL. My parents let me go on a walkabout at that early age. I hit the road with my best friend at the time, and we drove cross-country and hit LA, and then drove up the coast, and ended up at San Francisco, you know, the place with all this crazy music that I'd loved at that time, coming from hardcore and post-punk

Why does the author use "had loved ".It is not for temporal sequence because of  "at that time"which leaves no ambiguities about the time (I was about 17 years old) or may be to emphasize the duration of this period?

I don't know.  I would have used that I loved at that time.

This looks like a transcription of speech, so expect some odd phrasing as the mind works from one idea to another.  It's likely that this is a spoken mix up between something like "the music I'd listened to" and "the music I loved".
Taken literally, it is for the temporal sequence.  The author seems to suggest that he loved one piece of "crazy" music after another, perhaps in sequence, perhaps with each new piece of music replacing the previous one as «the music that he loved».  So at the narrative time, he didn't love each piece of music, they were "past loves".
But the phrasing is odd and clunky, and almost certainly the result of a fairly literal transcription of speech rather than a carefully written composition.  So don't think too much about it.  Feel free to treat it as a mistake in spoken English.

I'm not sure it can be cast as a mistake, even if I wouldn't write it. The 17 yr old might well exclaim "OMG, The Employees! I've loved their music for years!" And if casual speech leaves the "for years" to be implied, I'm not sure that's unreasonable.
